# get API details to console.log

Tags: json, api

Does anyone know why i can't see anything in my console.log?
* i checked that the value is registered by "alret"
* i took the the API link to browser and replaced the "value" with text to see that it works

```
 $(function () {

    var search = $('.navbar-form.navbar-left > button').click(function () {  
        var value = $('.form-group > input').val();

        getResults(value);

    });


    function getResults(value) {

        $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=' + value + '&api_key=117c571f879d54dfbfb2ffc0d98ff858&format=json', function (data) {

            console.log(data.artist);
            console.log(data.artist.name);
                    });
    }

});
```

Comment: are you getting a specific error?

Comment: no, console.log is empty

Comment: try just doing it with $.get() and set the content type to json.  .getJSON() can fail silently if the response isn't valid JSON, which is very strict.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? your `click` is most likely not being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your `getResults` function and it's working, the problem is probably your `click` listener not being called.

Comment: As i said :
 i checked that the value is registered by "alret", which means that my click must be called:  
 $(function () {

    var search = $('.navbar-form.navbar-left > button').click(function () {  
        var value = $('.form-group > input').val();

        alert(value);      //if the alert worked and i saw the value in the alert the click is working

    });

Answer (score 0):

i can't believe it, 2 hours for extra }); at the end of the code which screwed everything

Comment: it should have located after the .click event